# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, string, operands

Why am I getting the error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'str' and 'int' in my code?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ay5jO.png)

I was expecting it to print whole hours rented, but it came up with an error.

Comment: `get input` returns a `str` and an `int`, but then you swap them when you pass them as arguments, so `acc` is the `int`, `mins` is the `str`.

Comment: Use clearer variable names, and this type of error is harder to make.

Comment: The error is very clear: you're trying to divide a string by an integer, which is not allowed...

Answer (score 0):

It's an error we get when we try to add or do operations on incompatible or different data types. For example:

```
Integer, String
```

To avoid the error, either use `STR()` to convert to String from Integer `str(<Intiger Object>)` or `INT()` for String to Integer. Like `Int(<String Object>)`.